# Why i am getting license error while installing matlab in ubuntu

Tags: matlab

License checkout failed.
License Manager Error -8
Make sure the HostID of the license file matches this machine, and that the HostID on the SERVER
line matches the HostID of the license file.

Troubleshoot this issue by visiting: 
http://www.mathworks.com/support/lme/R2014a/8

Diagnostic Information:
Feature: MATLAB 
Licensing error: -8,523.

Comment: Well, have you read the solution from the link?

Comment: Please contact the Mathworks for licensing issues. If you're paying then for a license they will help you. If have a campus license, contact IT help desk at your campus.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a license issue. The license file might be corrupted. An easy fix is to replace the bin folder form matlab root directory.

Check this answer from matlab for more.

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100496-why-do-i-receive-license-manager-error-8